# NSInternalInconsistencyException on content offset

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error, tableview

Anytime I try to adjust my UITableView's content insets, I get a strange error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint constant is not finite!  That's illegal.  constant:nan firstAnchor:<NSLayoutDimension:0x60800026e5c0 "UIView:0x7fa7daa094a0.height"> secondAnchor:(null)'

which I've never gotten before. The code in concern is:

```
@IBOutlet weak private var tableReference: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableReference.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -79), animated: false)
}
```

edit: The error doesn't throw when I delete the contentOffset line.

Comment: content inset or content offset?

Comment: @Renatus Sorry—I meant offset. But the same thing happens whether it's inset or offset being set